# repeating set of operations for all selected objects individually

Tags: modeling, python, scripting

I wrote a short script which performs multiple operations on a selected objects, and some of those operations depend on the objects position. I have 100+ identical objects in different positions and I would like to apply this set of operations on each object. If I select all of the objects, is there a way to then iterate through each of the objects in this selection?

Apologies if this is a bit vague, I am fairly new to coding so I hope I am using the correct terminology. I was thinking perhaps all the selected objects could be put into an array and each one could be selected by incrementing the array index after performing all the operations.

Edit: For example

```
def execute(self, context):
    for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = object #was missing this part
        bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
        bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add()
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS')
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
        bpy.context.space_data.pivot_point = 'CURSOR'
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

This seems to only apply to the last object selected even though multiple objects are highlighted.

Update: I was missing "bpy.context.scene.objects.active = object". Adding that at the start of the loops fixes the problem.

Comment: If you provided more info about what set of operations you need to perform, it would be possible to answer this question more specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bpy

for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    object.location.z += 0.1 # Do whatever you want to the object
```

Comment: Updated with more information, apologies for the lack of detail in the original post. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Figured it out. Updated post with the missing part.